# Jquery Autocomplete source within same file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to implement this script within Wordpress (http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/) getting the Array from Wordpress database. The issue is that **Wordpress database connect $wpdb** won't work calling an external php like **demo_cities.php**

Can you tell me what the source would be if I integrate the **demo_cities.php** into the HTML? Is this even possible?

Can I create the array in Wordpress page and just call the rest of the script as it is?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ac_config = {
        source: "/ajax/demo_cities.php",
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#city").val(ui.item.city);
            $("#state").val(ui.item.state);
            $("#zip").val(ui.item.zip);
        },
        minLength:1
    };
    $("#city").autocomplete(ac_config);
});
</script>
<form action="#" method="post">
     <p><label for="city">City</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" /></p>
     <p><label for="state">State</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="" /></p>
     <p><label for="zip">Zip</label><br />
         <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="" /></p>
</form>
```

**demo_cities.php**

```
<?php

// Data could be pulled from a DB or other source
$cities = array(
    array('city'=>'New York', state=>'NY', zip=>'10001'),
    array('city'=>'Los Angeles', state=>'CA', zip=>'90001'),
    array('city'=>'Chicago', state=>'IL', zip=>'60601'),
    array('city'=>'Houston', state=>'TX', zip=>'77001'),
    array('city'=>'Phoenix', state=>'AZ', zip=>'85001'),
    array('city'=>'Philadelphia', state=>'PA', zip=>'19019'),
);

// Cleaning up the term
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

// Rudimentary search
$matches = array();
foreach($cities as $city){
    if(stripos($city['city'], $term) !== false){
        // Add the necessary "value" and "label" fields and append to result set
        $city['value'] = $city['city'];
        $city['label'] = "{$city['city']}, {$city['state']} {$city['zip']}";
        $matches[] = $city;
    }
}

// Truncate, encode and return the results
$matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5);
print json_encode($matches);

?>
```

Comment: For that you have to make a db connection and query on it

Comment: I already know how to make the db connection and get the **$cities array**. I need to know what would be the value for source if I want to include that foreach within 1 file

Comment: i am talking about mysqli_connect() in demo_cities.php